# Completely uninstall OCaml

Tags: uninstall

I want to completely uninstall OCaml so that I can Jane Street's Open Bundle. Using `sudo apt-get remove ocaml` seemed successful but OCaml is still present on my system (I can run the toploop, etc.) How can I remove it completely?

`apt-file show ../../../usr/bin/ocaml` doesn't return anything.

Solved: I used `find . -rexexp '.*ocaml[^/]*/? -exec rm -rf {} \;` in the `usr` directory to remove all ocaml-related files.

Comment: **Warning: this `find` command is dangerous**, it could remove files containing the name `ocaml` that are not supplied by the installer (e.g. file type associations which would be provided in bulk for many programs by a packacge which is absolutely not OCaml-specific) or any unrelated file whose name contains that string (some files and directories are named using a hash of something; if those hashes use base32 or base64. then the string `ocaml` could occur within… unlikely but when you have thousands of such files you could remove a random file without noticing).

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sudo apt-get purge ocaml
```

You also may have to reboot after.

Comment: apt-get says that the package doesn't exist, but the ocaml command is still there.